# How to create a lap time and session time format in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I would like to know how to format some cells in Excel for my fuel formula. I created a simple spreadsheet that is used to take the average lap time and total race session time to calculate the amount of fuel needed to finish the race. The formula I wrote works with decimal based numbers but I am wondering if I can make the spreadsheet better by formatting so someone types their actual lap time and session time, MM:SS.split. instead of having to type the times in decimal format which may become confusing

I wrote a function that will give me the correct fuel calculation but I want the cells to be custom formatted for lap times and session times instead of decimals and still show the total fuel needed as a regular number.

```
=A2*B2
```

Expected: |1:00|10:00| 10 Laps |

Actual: |1.00|10.00| 10|

Comment: The pipes denote different cells?

Comment: @Skin, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not going to perform any calculations on these numbers, then you can use the formula `TEXT()`. For the times, you can use something like the below where `m` means minutes and `s` means seconds and 1440 is 24 hours*60 minutes (1 in excel is equivalent to 1 day, so you need to divide by 1440 to make a day become a minute):

```
=TEXT(A1/1440,"mm:ss")
```

And the below for the laps:

```
=TEXT(A1, "#"" Laps""")
```

[image]

---

But if you have to perform calculation on these numbers, then you will have to format the cells directly instead of using the formula (Home > Format > Format Cells > Custom (Under General, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> on the cell) and use the formatting I used in the text formula, i.e. `mm:ss` and `# "Laps"` respectively. For the times however, you will have to manually divide by 1440.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And by manually calculate, you mean whipping out a real calculator and dividing the time?

Comment: @Tracer737 No, you will have to do like `=A1/1440` first, then use the formatting

Comment: ok well that is what I am looking for. I want some one to just enter the lap times: "1:00". The session time: "10:00". Then take both times, multiply them together to get the number of laps that it takes to finish the session, which would be 10 in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the data type of the cell to Time?